# Friend classes and header files

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, friend

I am writing a C++ program where I wish to use a friend class in order to access protected members of another class. Here is the header for the class I wish to access:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#include "../glm/glm.hpp"

// An enum class and some structs here

class Polygon {
public:
    // Constructors, destructor...
    Polygon();
    Polygon(int n_vertices, int n_indices);
    Polygon(int n_vertices, int n_indices, float* vertices, unsigned int* indices);
    ~Polygon();
    
    // Loads of other irrelevant functions go here
    
protected:
    // Bunches of other ivars before these
    unsigned int lastVBO;
    unsigned int lastVAO;
    unsigned int lastIBO;
    
    friend class Renderer;
};
```

And here is the declaration of the class which I wish to be its friend:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "../geometry/polygon.hpp"
#include "../geometry/rectangle.hpp"
#include "../geometry/circle.hpp"

class Renderer {
public:
    Renderer();
    ~Renderer();
    void queuePolygon(Polygon* p);
    void drawPolygons();
private:
    // Rectangle and Circle are children of Polygon
    // Which one of these gets called is determined in queuePolygon/drawPolygon
    void queueRectangle(Rectangle* r);
    void queueCircle(Circle* c);
    void drawRectangle(Rectangle* r);
    void drawCircle(Circle* c);
    
    std::vector<Rectangle*>* rectangleQueue;
    std::vector<Circle*>* circleQueue;
};
```

Now obviously what I want is to get access to the protected members IBO, VBO and VAO from the Polygon class, in order to draw that polygon using my renderer. Yet with this implementation, I don't have access to those ivars even with the friend declaration in the Polygon class. Importing the renderer header in `polygon.hpp` breaks the entire thing as subclasses no longer behave nicely.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First view result: Wrong design! If I see a "renderer" which provides separate methods for "rectangle, circle... " it looks wrong to me. A typical design should end up in splitting the "what" ( circle, rectangle ) and the "how", implemented in a set of render implementations. That you have to expose ( via friend, getters or public data ) internal data of objects is a bad idea.

Comment: You should probably clarify exactly what you mean by `"... breaks the entire thing as subclasses no longer behave nicely"`.  What errors/symptoms do you see?

Comment: Thank you @Klaus, I've recently started to implement the header. In the "prototype", drawing was handled internally in the Polygon class, which I wish to rectify. I might have to redesign.

Comment: @G.M. the subclasses no longer recognise Polygon as a base class.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the last comment but it sounds like the real problem may be [circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) amongst your classes.

Comment: I removed the buffer fields from the Polygon class as frankly, they don't belong there when I have a renderer. Moved it to the renderer, dropped the friend class thingy, and now things are both working and more tidy.